# 2 mathematical equations divided by each other

Tags: probability

Ok so this is quite hard to explain but please bare with me as I try.

I have two bags, each containing numbered balls. The first bag has 1-100 balls in it and the second bag has 1-10. I pull a ball from each bag at the same time and I'm going to divide the number of the ball from the first bag (1-100) with the number of the ball from the second bag (1-10). I want the equation of the division to be 10. No more and no less.

How do I go about calculating the probability of success? Considering that the numbers from both balls have to go with each other to produce the equation of 10, do I calculate 100x10 or do I do something different?

Thank you

Comment: So you do this "pull a ball from each bag and divide one by the other" ten times, adding all the results? Do you put the balls back after each time, or do you use all the balls in the 1-10 bag once each?

Comment: No not ten times just once. The balls are numbered. In the first bag they are numbered 1-100 and the second bag 1-10.

Answer (score 0):

So you are pulling once and want the division to give $10$. Let's first look at the outcomes this pull can give you:

$\{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),\ldots, (1,100),(2,1),(2,2),\ldots, (10,100)\}$

These are $1000$ possible outcomes. Now count the outcomes you want, e.g. $(10,100)$ would be nice, but also $(9,90)$ and let's say that the number of positive outcomes (the ones you want) is $a$.

Then the possibility you are looking for is $a/1000$.

Hope I got your question right, if not let me know.

Comment: Thank you! What if the second bag contains 100 balls as well? Would it be 100x100?

Comment: Ignore that comment haha

Comment: This works in a lot of settings like that: Assume we have a finite set of possible outcomes $M$ with size $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and a set of outcomes we are interested in: $N \subseteq M$ with size $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
As long as all elements of $M$ have the same probability, the chance for a positive outcome will always be $n/m$.